# Synchronous NSURLConnection https post request with JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode6

I need to make a HTTPS post request to a server using a synchronous connection. I've made plenty of http connections but for some reason the code doesn't work with https and I'm sure the website address is right.

Some of my code:

Note that dparam is a dictionary object.

```
NSError *err;
        NSData *parameterJSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dparam options:
                                     NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&err];
        NSString *param = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:parameterJSONData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"varnameOne=%@&varnameTwo=%@&param=%@",vone,vtwo,param];

        //my_url is a string defined elsewhere
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:my_url];


        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

I need to do this synchronously as I don't really have the time to change all my database calls to asynchronous and the calls need to either complete or fail before the program continues so it'd have to be made effectively synchronous anyway.

That said I did try a synchronous route but it didn't work with https only http.

Comment: after exicuting this line         NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error]; what is ur response code.use this after  NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
       NSLog(@"statusCode = %d", [httpResponse statusCode]);

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does the error parameter contain anything? Do you get a response? Be specific about what result this code gives you.

Comment: I actually wasn't getting a response code - seems that when testing the http connection, I'd turned airplane mode off then one. However unlike the iphone 6, the iphone 4 doesn't auto turn on the HTTP proxy - it was set to "Off" not "Manual". I'd reenabled wifi and was rather confused until I discovered this. I've still got errors, but I might be able to find a solution to those. Will post back later.

Comment: Is the website you're trying to connect to using a self signed SSL certificate?